# Why did Canadian Provincial leaders take the path to Confederation (on July 1, 1867) instead of separate states?

Tags: canada

Though Canadian Provincial leaders had a lot of divisions Sir John A. MacDonald and Sir George Cartier and others came to an agreement and made it possible to form a confederation.

Canadian Confederation (French: Confédération canadienne) was the process by which the British colonies of Canada, Nova Scotia, and New Brunswick were united into one Dominion of Canada on July 1, 1867. –

Can anybody tell me was it because of pure compromising and sacrificing mentality that it was possible to form a Confederation? Or Were there any other components to it? For example, building a trans-Pacific railway road. Or to avoid the civil war. Or giving special privilege.

Comment: This question would benefit from preliminary research.  I am uncomfortable with the notion that there is an identifiable cause to the confederation.  When did this happen?

Comment: It was the fear of what 300,000 idle and just released Union Army troops might do under the wrong POTUS, actually. It was British Columbia that was enticed in by the promise of a Transcontinental railway, in 1870.